# Clicking link in android WebView not starting download of file

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to download file when user clicks on link in WebView. The action works properly when I do the same action in chrome app, but it doesn't work in webview. I have referred multiple questions and tried implementing solutions provided but it doesn't work.

Stackoverflow questions referred and tried solutions mentioned.

[Download file inside WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)

[Android Webview not triggering a href download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882785/android-webview-not-triggering-a-href-download-file)

[How to download files from webview Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864098/how-to-download-files-from-webview-android)

WebView code that I used,

```
    wv_main.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv_main.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wv_main.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv_main.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    wv_main.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    wv_main.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wv_main.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
    wv_main.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    wv_main.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    wv_main.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

            request.setDescription("Download file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    wv_main.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        private int webViewPreviousState;
        private final int PAGE_STARTED = 0x1;
        private final int PAGE_REDIRECTED = 0x2;

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            // Get cert from SslError
            SslCertificate sslCertificate = error.getCertificate();
            Certificate cert = getX509Certificate(sslCertificate);
            if (cert != null && certificate != null) {
                try {
                    // Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#verify(java.security.PublicKey)
                    cert.verify(certificate.getPublicKey()); // Verify here...
                    handler.proceed();
                } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchProviderException | SignatureException e) {
                    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
            webViewPreviousState = PAGE_REDIRECTED;
            wv_main.loadUrl(urlNewString);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;
            Log.e("Start Loading", "Start Loading.........");
            /*if (dialog == null || !dialog.isShowing())
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading", true, true);*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {
                //dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("Loading Done", "Loading Done.........");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
                                    WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            Toast.makeText(SecretLinkBrowserActivity.this, "Error:" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    wv_main.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {

            Log.d("LogTag", message);
            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

While debugging I noticed that when I click on link the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is not being called. The way website is doing the download is they have used `doPostBack()` that generated the url dynamically and downloads the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you do this steps in Kotlin you can Download files from any WebView 

1- Add these to your Manifest 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 

2- Add these settings to your webview 

val webViewSettings = binding.your@id@webview(InsideXML).settings 

        webViewSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true //Needed 

        webViewSettings.domStorageEnabled = true //Needed 

        webViewSettings.allowFileAccess = true //Needed 

        webViewSettings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true //Needed 

----Yo can have more here but this are needed ----- 

3-Handle the downloads 

   //handle downloading 

        binding.wvBase.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType, _ -> 

            val request = DownloadManager.Request( 

                Uri.parse(url) 

            ) 

            request.setMimeType(mimeType) 

            val cookies: String = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url) 

            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies) 

            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent) 

           // request.setDescription("Downloading File...") 

            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType)) 

            // request.allowScanningByMediaScanner() 

        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED) 

            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir( 

                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName( 

                    url, contentDisposition, mimeType 

                ) 

            ) 

            val dm = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager 

            dm.enqueue(request) 

            alertdialog() 

        } 

In my case I have a custom alert Dialog to control if user says no, yes
```

Answer (score -1):

You could launch a new intent and allow the user to choose another app for downloading like this:

```
wv_main.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
});
```

But I suppose you want to use download manager, you are missing the setDestinationUri method call, should be something like this

```
DownloadManager.Request request=new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
           .setTitle("Dummy File")// Title of the Download Notification
           .setDescription("Downloading")// Description of the Download Notification
           .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)// Visibility of the download Notification
           .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file))// Uri of the destination file
           .setRequiresCharging(false)// Set if charging is required to begin the download
           .setAllowedOverMetered(true)// Set if download is allowed on Mobile network
           .setAllowedOverRoaming(true);// Set if download is allowed on roaming network
```

Comment: thing is that on download start is not triggered when I click the link.